# Firebase: Reporting Analytics and Crash Data to Separate Projects

Tags: android, ios, firebase, crashlytics, firebase-analytics

Recently I came across [this article](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects) from firebase, which details how to access multiple projects from a single application. This is great, and potentially very useful, however I have been unable to find a way to separate out using Analytics and Crash reporting into separate projects.

The reason we would like to do this is so that our clients have full access to their analytics, whilst keeping the crash logs in a different project that only we can access.

I did see that on the article it states:

> Note: On Android and iOS, Analytics are only logged for the default app.

which would be fine, provided we can change where the crashes are logged, but I haven't seen any mention of Crashlytics in this.

I guess the question comes down to is it possible to do this, or is it something that is not (yet) supported?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mike @ Google here.

Firebase now supports more granular permissions, so you should be able to grant only Google Analytics access to a client without exposing the rest of Firebase data/functionality to them. To do so, you can use the "Assign Firebase Roles" feature when you are adding them to the project - likely you would select the Analytics View role for your client users. Please see [IAM overview](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/iam/overview) for more details.

Supporting more than one client with a common Crashlytics project is not feasible. The article you referenced on multi-project setup works at a high level for other Firebase features, but Crashlytics benefits from Analytics data to provide user-level metrics for impacted users. As you note, Analytics data will only be logged for the first app configuration, so Crashlytics would not deliver the best reporting without Analytics info.

In this scenario, I'd recommend you split each client's app into individual projects, and grant each client user only Analytics View access to their corresponding app's project via the [IAM overview](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/iam/overview) method described above.

Comment: Thanks mike - this is an option we have considered but unfortunately it doesn’t work for situations where the client already owns a firebase account they want us to use for their analytics as they are in control of the account permissions. However I agree this is a good workaround when we are the ones in control of the account. The information on how crashlytics and analytics interact is also very useful!